# Display lines outside multiline comment block

Tags: perl, text-processing

I am trying to filter out Multi-line comments from a Unix file. We will use that file to run against Oracle engine

I tried to use below but it doesn't show proper output I want.

My file file.sql contains this:

```
/* This is commented section
asdasd...
asdasdasd...
adasdasd..
sdasd */
I want this line to print
/* Dont want this to print */
/* Dont want this
  to print
  */
Want this to 
  print
    /*
Do not want 
this to print
*/
```

My output needs to be like below::

```
I want this line to print
Want this to 
  print
```

I have tried using below perl to first show me the lines inside the Multiline comment, but it doesn't show proper output :(

```
perl -ne 'print if //*/../*//' file.sql
```

My main goal is the not show the multiline comment line and just display the output as earlier mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. This seems to do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  print unless m[/\*] .. m[\*/];
}

__DATA__
/* This is commented section
asdasd...
asdasdasd...
adasdasd..
sdasd */
I want this line to print
/* Dont want this to print */
/* Dont want this
  to print
  */
Want this to 
  print
    /*
Do not want 
this to print
*/
```

Output:

```
I want this line to print
Want this to 
  print
```

The problem was with the two match operators that you were using at either end of the flip-flop (`//*/../*//`).

Firstly, if you use a slash as the delimiter on the match operator, then any slashes in your regex need to be escaped. I've got round that by switching from slashes (`/ ... /`) to using `m[ ... ]` instead.

Secondly, the `*` has a special meaning in a regex (it means "zero or more of the previous thing") so you need to escape those.

So we end up with `m[/\*] .. m[\*/]`.

Oh, and you need to reverse your logic. You're using `if` when it should be `unless`.

Converting to a command-line script like the one you've used:

```
perl -ne 'print unless m[/\*] .. m[\*/]' file.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
perl -0777 -pe's{/\*.*?\*/}{}sg' file.sql
```

**Output**:

```
I want this line to print


Want this to 
  print
```

**Explanation**:

- `-0777` : slurp mode
- modifier flag `s`: make the dot match new lines
- modifier flag `g`: globally match the pattern repeatedly

Comment: Perfectly works for me and the requirement. You are awesome.